# Visibility of inner class explanation

Tags: java, scope, inner-classes

I want to compare two things. We know that:

1. Inner class can access every member from Outer class.
2. Outer class can't access members from Inner class.. unless you make an object of Inner class.

My question is why is that? Why can't Outer class access members of Inner class as well? Here is example to make it quite clear:

```
public class OuterClass {
    String stringOuter;

    void m1(){
       //can call just stringOuter
       InnerClass i = new InnerClass();
       i.stringInner; //can call stringInner when you make object
    }

    class InnerClass{
        String stringInner;

        void m2(){
            //can call stringOuter and stringInner
            //doesn't need object from OuterClass
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OuterClass can access InnerClass data members depending on their type (static or non static). For non-static data members, access is allowed via objects and for static data-members, access is allowed via Class name (example explained below).

As per your example, the **InnerClass** is having non-static data members and they are only accessible through objects. That is why you're able to access the **stringInner** via object. If you'd declare a static data member in **InnerClass** then you can directly access it through **InnerClass.staticDataMember**.

Whenever we create an object of a class, it allocates a memory which consists of all the non-static data members. As these data members are part of that object, due to which we can access these data members via **object.dataMember** statement.

I hope it clarifies your answer?

Comment: Yes, all clear. Outer sees Inner as same as any other class. But how can Inner class access everything in Outer without making object of type Outer? Shouldn't they work the 'same'?

Comment: First of all, your inner class isn't private so anyone who has access to OuterClass can access InnerClass as well like **OuterClass.InnerClass**.

When you create an instance of outer class then you can access innerclass's non-static data member through outerClassObject.innerClassNonStaticObject.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `stringOuter` and `stringInner` are *fields*, not methods. Hence, you can not “call” them and your example of `i.stringInner;` still doesn’t compile, as it is not a statement.

To make the example valid, we may assign the values of the fields to another variable.

```
public class OuterClass {
    String stringOuter;

    void m1() {
       InnerClass i = new InnerClass();
       String s = i.stringInner;
    }

    class InnerClass {
        String stringInner;

        void m2() {
            String s = stringOuter;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why `void m2() { String s = stringOuter; }` works, is that an inner class, in contrast to a nested class which has the `static` modifier, always has an associated instance of the outer class.

Your example method `m2()` is equivalent to

```
void m2() {
    OuterClass o = OuterClass.this;
    String s = o.stringOuter;
}
```

In your example, the initialization of reference to the outer class instance is implicit, which only works in a context where an instance of the `OuterClass` is in scope. So when you change the `m1()` method to

```
static void m1() {
   InnerClass i = new InnerClass(); // compiler error
   String s = i.stringInner;
}
```

it doesn’t work anymore, as there is no instance of the `OuterClass`. You can provide an explicit instance instead:

```
static void m1() {
    OuterClass outer = new OuterClass();
    InnerClass i = outer.new InnerClass(); // uses outer
    String s = i.stringInner;
}
```

But this is a rarely used feature of the Java programming language.

As said, if you change the inner class to a nested class, you can instantiate it without an instance of the outer class, but you also can not access non static members without specifying an instance explicitly:

```
public class OuterClass {
    String stringOuter;

    static void m1() {
        InnerClass i = new InnerClass(); // no problem
        String s = i.stringInner;
    }

    static class InnerClass {
        String stringInner;

        void m2() {
            String s1 = new OuterClass().stringOuter; // works
            String s = stringOuter; // does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose class declarations are just the templates and that applies to Inner classes also , unless you instantiate an object from the inner class(template) or any other class you can't access its members . The exception is static members as they reside in class area .

Comment: True, my issue in on the note that Inner can access everything directly. Unlike Outer, that needs to make an instance of Inner to access instance members or using class name to access static members. Why is that? :/